# Input field not updating. Parent Class with function component child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am learning react and tried to update the input field. I am trying to make a hierarchical form.
I have a class component *Body* and functional component or child component *Form*. I have object in Body state and updating it in Form. both are in separate files. It is failing to update the input field while the function is called and and state is set to keystrokes.

```
class Body extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            users : [],
            user: {
                userName: '',
                setUserName : name => {this.setState({userName : name}); console.log(this.state.userName)},
                city: '',
                setCity : city => { this.state.city = city},
                cnic: '',
                setCNIC : cnic => { this.state.cnic = cnic},
                address: '',
                setAddress : address => { this.state.address = address}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Form.js

```
const onChange = (event, updater) => {
    updater(event.target.value)
    //console.log(event.target.value)
}

function UserForm (props){
    //console.log(props) 
    return(
      <form>
            <label>
                Name:
                <input name="userName" value = {props.user.userName} onChange = {event => onChange(event, props.user.setUserName)}>
                </input>
            </label>
      </form>
           )
}
```

There is no typo in file name of Form.js. The function component is UserForm and file name is Form.js.
I am passing props and updating values. but no change in input field and its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the setter functions (ie `setUserName()`, `setCity()`, etc) that you've defined in the `user` object of the `Body` components initial state are applying the state updates to a different "location" in the state object than what you're expecting.

The `setState()` function applies state updates relative to the root of the components `state` object.

In your case, that would mean that invoking `setUserName` with argument `"bob"`, the `Body` components state would be updated to:

```
{ 
users :[], 
user : { /* existing object */ }, 
userName : "bob" /* Update applied relative to root of state object */
}
```

To achieve "nested state updates" (ie updating `state.user.userName`), consider updating your setter functions in the following way:

```
setUserName : name => {
    this.setState({ 
        // Update existing user object with replacement
        user : { 
            ...this.state.user, // Clone existing user in state
            userName : name // Update the userName field in cloned user 
        }
    })
}
```

Hope that helps!